# The role of keys in a react-redux app and managing the state of dynamic components

Tags: reactjs, redux

I understand basically what keys are for: we need to be able to identify changes in a list of children.

What I'm having trouble with is the information flow, and maintaining synchronicity between the states in my store and the states of subcomponents.

For example, say I have a list of `<CustomTextInput>` which is exactly what it sounds like. Some container with a text input inside of it. Many of them are stored in some `<CustomTextInputList>` element.

The number of `CustomTextInput`s in the list can change, they can be added and subtracted. I have a factory with an incrementing counter that issues new keys every time a CustomTextInput is inserted, no matter where it's placed.

I have a `CustomTextInputModel` type which populates my store. Whenever I change the value inside one of the inputs, it needs to call a callback which dispatches actions in my store. But then how do I know which one to modify, and how can I be sure that the whole list doesn't rerender from changing a single instance since the entire store's state is being recreated? Do I need to store a reference to some model ID in every `CustomTextInput`? Should this be the key?

Manythanks, I'm very new at this :)

Answer (score 4):

> But then how do I know which one to modify, and how can I be sure that the whole list doesn't re-render from changing a single instance since the entire store's state is being recreated?

If your component is tied to a list of objects in the redux store, then it will re-render the whole list since the parent would be getting new props. However there are a few ways to avoid the re-render.

Note that this is a pretty advanced post, but hopefully it helps. I find [this page](http://somebody32.github.io/high-performance-redux/) to be useful in explaining one way to make a react-redux application more performant in rendering large lists by having each item connected to the redux store and listening to itself via an id that is passed in via a prop.

*Edit* Heres another good article that illustrates the point: https://medium.com/devtravel/optimizing-react-redux-store-for-high-performance-updates-3ae6f7f1e4c1#.3ltrwmn3z

Inside of the Reducer:

```
function items(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MARK':
      const item = state[action.id];
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: {...item, marked: !item.marked}
      };
    default: return state;
  }
}

function ids(state = [], action) {
  return state;
}
```

In the list container:

```
<div>
  {
    ids.map(id => {
      return <Item key={id} id={id} />;
    })
  }
</div>

// Returns an array of just ids, not whole objects
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {id: state.ids};
}
```

Inside of the Item component:

```
// Uses id that is passed from parent, returns the item at the index equal to the id
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const { id } = props;
  const { items } = state;
  return {
    item: items[id],
  };
}

const markItem = (id) => ({type: 'MARK', id});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {markItem}
)(Item);
```

> Do I need to store a reference to some model ID in every CustomTextInput?

Yes, you will need some type of key/id to pass to the redux actions when you would like to make a modification to that specific item.

> Should this be the key?

Most common way to reference something in the in the redux store would be by id.